# The upper bound of the sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

If $y_n$ is a nonincreasing series of real numbers and $0\leq y_n\leq1 $ for $n\geq 0$, $y_0 = 1$ and we know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n \leq A $, then is there a way to find a tight upper bound for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n^m $, where $m$ is an integer number?

Comment: $y(n)=-1$. Then $\sum_n y(n)<0$. But $\sum (y(n))^2$ is unbounded. Do you want the numbers to be non-negative?

Comment: yes, actually they are positive numbers all between 0 and 1.

Comment: and also $y_0 = 1$.

Answer (score 7):

For positive integers $m$, let $N$ be an index for which $y(n)<1$ for all $n>N$.
An upper bound for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(y(n))^m$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}(y(n))^m+A-\sum_{n=0}^{N}y(n)$$

Answer (score 4):

A different bound:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n^m=y_0^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Bigl(\frac{y_n}{y_0}\Bigr)^m\le y_0^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y_n}{y_0}=y_0^{m-1}\,A.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, actually the $y_n$s are between 0 and 1, $y_0 = 1$ and I need a tighter bound for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n^m$ than A.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming positive terms,

$$y_n\ge1\implies y_n^m\ge y_n$$ then as the original series converges

$$B:=\sum_{n=0,y_n\ge1}^\infty(y_n^m-y_n)$$

is finite and

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(y_n^m-y_n)\le B$$ or $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n^m<A+B.$$